# register is not defined

Tags: javascript, html

im getting this error when i run my code
VM120 signup.html:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: register is not defined
at HTMLInputElement.onclick (VM120 signup.html:1:1)

im making a code that detects when i press the submit btn
html:

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> signing up </title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../layout/styles/signupstyle.css">
   </head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h2>sign up</h2>
    <form action="#">
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your first name" id="firstname" required>
          </div>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your last name" id="lastname" required>
        </div>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your birthdate" id="birthdate" required>
        </div>
      <div class="input-box">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email" id="email" required>
      </div>
      <div class="input-box">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Create password" id="password" required>
      </div>
      <div class="input-box">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm password" id="confirmpassword" required>
      </div>
      <div class="input-box button">
        <input type="Submit" value="Register Now" onclick="register()">
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <h3>Already have an account? <a href="login.html">Login now</a></h3>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="../layout/scripts/signup.js"></script>
</html>

javascript:
function register(){
    let 1stname=document.getElementById("firstname")
    console.log("hi "+1stname)
}
```

i searched every where but i couldn't find a problem

Comment: Your definition of `register` isn't in the right place.

Comment: what does that mean

Comment: what am i supposed to do

Comment: @somename: Move the `<script>` element to just before the closing `</body>` tag, and check your browser's debugging tools to see if the request to `signup.js` succeeded at all and returned the content you expect.

Comment: what is browsers debugging tool?

Comment: @somename: In Chrome you can access the development tools by pressing F12.  You can also use your favorite search engine to find how to access and use your browser's development/debugging tools.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you can't start variable names with numbers, that's probably why your code is not working. Try renaming it to firstName or just add an underscore (`_1name`).

```
function register() {
    let firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    console.log("hi " + firstname);
}
```